# Sharepoint 2013 - Workflow suddenly stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sql-server

I have a custom workflow which has suddenly failed. The workflow sends an email, copies the form list to another forms list and then deletes the original form list.

I have read it may be a sql database issue - I have no error and nothing in the logs to indicate what the issue may be.

Any advice would be welcome.

To add more detail.

This is a subsite - I have other subsites containing workflows which have not failed. It is isolated to this one workflow. Where should I begin?

Comment: is this designer workflow?

Comment: Yes it is......

Answer (score 0):

Please check the recent updates installed. In Sept there was sec update for .net that brakes some of the wf actions. Maybe some of your OS updates are delayed based on company policy.

https://borncity.com/win/2018/09/17/sharepoint-issues-after-installing-kb4457916-net-update/

There is public MS KB on it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

Answer (score 0):

I had workflows do this as well due to a recent migration.  I placed all the steps within an 'Impersonation Step' and they started working.  Maybe this will work for you as well?